# remove $_SESSION var but not its content in php

Tags: php, session, var, unset

```
$session = &$_SESSION;
```

I acces $_SESSION by this var: $session;

How can I remove $_SESSION var without deleting its content ?

I want to can acces session data only from $session var.

Can you please give me any solution?

Note: I don't need to know if it's helpful or not.

#### Edit:

I get session's address (&$_SESSION) because I want also to make live modifications in $_SESSION (but using $session var).

I want my $session modifications to exists (in $_SESSION) after refresh page, but I don't want to can access directly $_SESSION.

Comment: What are your concerns with needing to remove the superglobal `$_SESSION`? Deleting a variable while keeping the contents doesn't make technical sense. Just `$session = $_SESSION; unset($_SESSION);` good luck setting session variables.

Comment: I think `$session = $_SESSION;` is what you want. Then you can destroy the session. This seems strange though.

Comment: No seriously... why?

Comment: @castis, "I don't need to know if it's helpful or not.". I don't want to lose $_SESSION data. I want to can modify it from $session.

Comment: You `want also to make live modifications in $_SESSION` or `remove $_SESSION`? This is unclear. You can't modify something that is destroyed/unset/removed. Your `$session` is a reference to `$_SESSION`.

Comment: I want to make live modifications in $_SESSION from $session reference. And I also want TO NOT CAN acces session directly from $_SESSION ("but using $session var").

Comment: @ValentinTanasescu im not particularly concerned with what you need, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this to perform what you are intending to... Hope you'll get this `$session = htmlentities(var_export($_SESSION, true));`

Comment: Can I still access $_SESSION ?! Cause I would like to not. I want my $session modifications to exists (in $_SESSION) after refresh page but I don't want to can access directly $_SESSION;

Comment: So, you want that data in the $_SESSION varible must be gone or deleted??

Comment: Only gone. To not can acces it directly. I want to only can acces/change it from the reference $session var.

Comment: session_unset(); try this to unset values from $_SESSION